# Optimize the path length in a KaryTree

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

I have a engineering problem that I found suitable in formulating it in graphs. A source node supplies pressure or whatever. Each node (vertex) has two edges of a certain e.g. pressure loss...whatever. At the end all sink (end) nodes shall see the same resistance starting from the source. This is the GraphDistance for the path from source node to sink node. The edge's pressure loss is translated into EdgeWeights. I have a list of nodes with two edges of individual edge weights, equivalent to valves with two channels of different pressure loss. The goal is now to place the available nodes with its EdgeWeigts for each of the two edges to minimize the difference in path length for the sink nodes.
In lack of more intelligent approach: The brute force approach of permutating all available nodes to all vertex positions is taken.
The code is shown below. It works well for a KaryTree of 7 nodes and 20 different available "nodes" (valves). However, my application has much more nodes. Which makes the calculation time increasing massively for both permutation building as well as path length calculation (ParallelTable).

Is there a substantial speed up in the code possible?
Is there an alternative faster way to takle the issue? Also outside the graph world.

```
(*definition of the tree*)
treeNodes = 7;
tgX[] = KaryTree[treeNodes, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
tgX[vv_] := 
  KaryTree[treeNodes, EdgeWeight -> vv, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

```
(*number of relevant nodes, that shall have equal length in the end*)
anzahlEnden = 4;(*Anzahl der relevaten Enden bis zu denen die
Streckenlänge von Node 1 berechnet werden sollen*)
endNodes = VertexList[tgX[]][[-anzahlEnden ;;]]
(*amount of edges*)
kantenAnzahl = Length[EdgeList[tgX[]]];

(*This function is used to calculate the deviation of the length (weight)of the relevant nodes. It shall be minimum.*)
merit[kk_] := RootMeanSquare[kk - Mean[kk]]

anzahlTeile = 10;(*number of parts in the shelf*)
shelf = Table[a[i], {i, anzahlTeile}];(*unique labeling of the parts*)
set = Permutations[shelf, {kantenAnzahl/2}];(*make all permutations possible to fill the tree and use 
all parts available *)
parts = Table[
  RandomInteger[{0, 7}, 2], {i, 
   anzahlTeile}];(*Random weights (e.g. length or resistance) for the 
two edges of each node/vertex*)

(*All possible permutations to form a tree as given from the parts as 
available. The part number gets a random edge weight (Random will 
later be measurement values from stock parts)*)
perma = set /. 
   Rule @@@ 
    Transpose[{shelf, 
      parts}];(*Edge weight List, with all possibilities of tree 
forming. *)
Length[perma](*number of unique trees to calculate through equivalent to anzahlTeile!/(anzahlTeile - kantenAnzahl/2)! *)

(*From the source node to all relevant sink nodes, the distance is 
calculated. This is repeated for all possible permutations of parts 
at each vertex [stupid brute force :-( ] *)
AbsoluteTiming[aa = Table[
    GraphDistance[tgX[Flatten[perma[[i]]]], 1, #] & /@ endNodes, {i, 
     1, Length[perma]}];]
(*merit values are calculated for each of the trees with individual
part configuration. Lowest value wins*)
rr = merit[#] & /@ aa;
(*and the winner is...*)
best = Position[rr, Min[rr]][[1, 1]]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me - specifically, this line seems wrong: `set = Permutations[shelf, {kantenAnzahl #7 2}]`

Comment: Sorry, it should be:
```set = Permutations[shelf, {kantenAnzahl/2}];```

Comment: Somehting that happenend during copying. I tested the code now. It should work. Btw. for ```anzahlTeile = 20;(*number of parts in the shelf*)``` , the AbsoluteTiming takes 2.5s.

Comment: I took out in the code above, the ParallelTable and made it Table, only. That gives a factor of two speed increase. Although I thought the problem is well parallelizeable.